# Source Control System for Binary File

Tags: flash, svn, version-control

We use subversion, which works great for software projects. We also have a lot of flash projects, which we don't use any kind of source control. Each flash project contain quite a few images. The time frame of each project is a couple weeks, but few can go upto a couple months.

The number of files we create contribute to quite a bit of file size. To keep repository size at a minimum, we want to keep the latest version only and wipe out previous history once a project is finished. History is useless to us after a project is finished.

It looked into subversion, but it doesn't allow to remove anything from the repository. I need to perform this workaround [here](http://creatingwithcode.com/howto/extracting-projects-from-shared-svn/).

One easy way is creating a separate repository for each project. When the project is over, save the latest version to archive and wipe out the repository. The number of active projects is about 50 - 100. Is there any issue with creating one repository per project?

Or is there other source control system support this feature?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't understand why the history is useless after *finishing* a project. When are your projects finished? After the release? Are your products error free? ...

However, I can see no problems with one repository per project - this should be the easiest approach - and there is no need for changing the vcs.

Also this article might be interesting for you: [Delete parts of subversion history](http://robmayhew.com/delete-parts-of-subversion-history/)